# Testing app on iPad 1 (iOS 5.1.1) using Xcode 6.2

Tags: ios, ios5, xcode6, 64-bit

When I launch my app using Xcode 6.2 on an iPad 1 running iOS 5.1.1, I get the following error:

[image: Unsupported Run Configuration: Xcode cannot install or launch applications supporting the 64-bit architecture on devices running iOS version prior to 6.0]

I couldn't find any documentation on how to exclude this architecture. Any ideas? My app's deployment target is set to 5.1.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in `arm64` architecture in VALID_ARCHS.

Removing arm64 from VALID_ARCHS solves the issue. In my case I had to create a separate branch for testing on iOS 5 devices.

[image]

then try to run app.

**Set this Setting your Xcode**

1. ARCHS = `armv7 armv7s`
2. VALID_ARCHS = `armv7 armv7s arm64`
3. In this case, binary will be built for `armv7 armv7s arm64`
   architectures. But the same binary will run on ONLY ARCHS = `armv7`
   `armv7s`.

Comment: He is right but you should keep in mind that Apple won't approve you app anymore if you don't support the 64bit architecture.

Comment: Yeah, I just figured that out as well. I removed the arm64 just temporarily to test on iOS 5.1.1. We don't need extensive testing since we're just supporting it as a courtesy :) Then, I put the arm64 back in when I submit. From the error message I assume that iPad 1 users *will* be able to download it. Is that your understanding as well?